# Page sized incorrectly on mobile

Tags: html, css

This problem is related to the website currently under websitetesting.pro which I am editing some things on for a friend.
He's using the template pluton for some parts of it, but that's not the problem.
The issue is regarding the size of the website on mobile devices. On desktop, the page sizes perfectly, however on mobile, you are able to zoom out, making the page look like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEugB.jpg)

The problem is somewhere in the stylesheet currently named "ksytles"
Here are the contents:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:800,700,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,600);

/* Reset
---------------------------------*/
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.figure {
    margin: 0px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

a, a:hover, a:active {
    outline: 0px !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: '\0020';
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
} 
a.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0 50px;
}
/* Common style */
.grid figure {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 1%;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 480px;
    max-height: 360px;
    width: 48%;
    background: #3085a3;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.grid figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.grid figure figcaption {
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.grid figure figcaption::before,
.grid figure figcaption::after {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.grid figure figcaption,
.grid figure figcaption > a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Anchor will cover the whole item by default */
/* For some effects it will show as a button */
.grid figure figcaption > a {
    z-index: 1000;
    text-indent: 200%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.grid figure h2 {
    word-spacing: -0.15em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.grid figure h2 span {
    font-weight: 800;
}

.grid figure h2,
.grid figure p {
    margin: 0;
}

.grid figure p {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 68.5%;
}

/* Styles
---------------------------------*/
body {
    background: #1A2328;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #888888;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #D2D2D2;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0px 0 25px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #60B10F;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888888;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}

p {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Header Styles
---------------------------------*/

#header_wrapper {
    background: #60B10F;
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

.header_box {
    position: relative;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.res-nav_click {
    display: none;
}


/* Nav Styles
---------------------------------*/
#main-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: #EAEAEA;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar {
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #D9F5BE;
}

.navStyle {
    float: right;
}

.navStyle ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    float: initial;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navStyle ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    float: initial;
}

.navStyle ul li:first-child {
    /*margin:0px;*/;
}

.navStyle ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0 23px;
}

.navStyle ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navStyle ul li a:hover {
    color: #ED5441;
}

.navStyle > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ED5441;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navStyle > li.active > a,
.navStyle > li.active > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ED5441;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.borderLeft {
    border-left: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.borderTop {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #DADADA;
}

.mrgTop {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.form-control{background: transparent;padding: 20px 15px;border-radius: 0;border: none;border-bottom: solid 1px #656565;}
.btn-primary {
    color: #2D2D2D;
    background-color: #60B10F;
    border-color: #60B10F;
    padding: 10px 34px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-primary:hover{
    background-color: #6BC114;
    border-color: #6CC314;
    color: #FBFBFB;
}
/* Top_content
---------------------------------*/

.top_cont_outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 750px;
    background: url('../img/home2.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.top_cont_outer:before{content:'';position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:5;background: rgba(23, 26, 29, 0.39);height:100%;bottom:0;}
.hero_section {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 72px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.white_pad {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.white_pad img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.top_left_cont {
    padding: 110px 0;
}

.top_left_cont h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #f56eab;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.top_left_cont h2 {
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 77px;
    text-transform: initial;
}

.top_left_cont h2 strong {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #62C400;
}

.top_left_cont p {color: #E4E4E4;margin: 0 0 40px 0;line-height: 38px;font-size: 22px;text-align: center;letter-spacing: 1px;font-weight: normal;text-transform: capitalize;}

a.read_more, a.read_more2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 178px;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: transparent;
    color: #FEB11E;
    border: 1px solid #FEB11E;
    margin:0 auto;
}
a.read_more{
     color: #3C3C3C;
     border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
}
a.read_more2:hover, a.read_more:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #0593F9;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
a.read_more:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #ED5441;
    border: 1px solid #ED5441;
}

.social_links {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.social_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
}

.social_links li a {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #C1C1C1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.social_links li a:hover, .social_links li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 80px;
}

.twitter a:hover {
    color: #55acee;
}

.facebook a:hover {
    color: #3b5998;
}

.pinterest a:hover {
    color: #cb2026;
}

.gplus a:hover {
    color: #dd4b39;
}


/* Animation Timers
---------------------------------*/
.delay-02s {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.delay-03s {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.delay-04s {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.delay-05s {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.delay-06s {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.delay-07s {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.delay-08s {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.delay-09s {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}

.delay-1s {
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}

.delay-12s {
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
}

/*---------------------------------------
   SECTION TESTIMONIAL              
-----------------------------------------*/

#owl-demo .item {
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#owl-demo .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.testimonial {
    background: url(../img/TestimonialBG.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.testimonial .section_overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 5px;
}
div.carousel-inner .item img {
    border: 2px solid #f39c12;
    border-radius: 0%;
    padding: 1px;
}
.testimonial_caption {
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.testimonial_caption p {
    color: #D8D8D8;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
.testimonial_caption h2 {
    color: #f39c12;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.testimonial_caption h4 {
    color: #f39c12
}
.testimonial_caption h4 span {
    color: #D8D8D8;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.testimonial ol.carousel-indicators li {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #f39c12;
    margin: 1PX
}
.testimonial ol.carousel-indicators li.active {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border: 0px solid #f39c12;
    background: #f39c12;
}
/*---------------------------------------
   SECTION CALL TO ACTION              
-----------------------------------------*/

.call_to_action {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.call_to_action p {
    color: #dfdfdf;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.call_to_action a {} .btn-action,
.btn-action:active,
.btn-action:focus,
.btn-action:visited {
    background: #f39c12;
    border: 1px solid #f39c12;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.btn-action:hover {
    background: #FF6B80;
    border-color: #FF6B80;
}



#footer {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-color: #60B10F;
}
#footer a {
    color: #fff;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
#footer a:hover,
#footer a:focus {
    color: #FFCA6F;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
/*
3.3 About
******************************************************************/
 .team .thumbnail {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.team .thumbnail:hover .social {
    z-index: 5;
}
.team .thumbnail:hover .social a {
    color:#fff;
}
.team .thumbnail .mask {
    background: #FECE1A;
}
.team .thumbnail .mask h2 {
    margin-top:20%;
}
.team .thumbnail .mask, .team .thumbnail .mask h3, .team .thumbnail .mask p, .team .thumbnail:hover h3, .team .thumbnail:hover .social a:hover {
    color:#181A17;
}
.about-text {
    margin-top:30px;
}
.about-text p {
    padding:0;
    font-size:16px;
}
/*********************************************************************
                        SKILLS BAR
*********************************************************************/
 .skills {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    margin:0px;
}
.skills li {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    background:#FFF;
    height:40px;
    padding:1px;
}
.skills li h3 {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #181A1C;
}
.skills li .bar {
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FECE1A;
}
#snow-effect {
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 450px;

}
*{cursor:url(../img/cursor.png),auto!important}html{font-size:62.5%}
}
```

My question is what needs to be removed/changed in this stylesheet for the website to size properly on all devices?

Comment: Please post the actual code rather than a link to it.

Comment: Actually, the problem is _probably_ not in the stylesheet at all..but on the `<meta name="viewport" ...>` tag on the HTML (or lack thereof). See [the MSDN docs of viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: @JCOC611, I don't think that's the issue. I removed the link to that stylesheet from the page and the problem was gone.

Comment: Anyone got any idea?